# BluetoothAdapter using ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth, bluetooth-device-discovery

I am trying to use BluetoothAdapter with `ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE` to discover my phone to other users according to this:

```
     testIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
     startActivity(testIntent);
```

I get the dialog box of Bluetooth Permission Request, but for some reason I can't see it on my activity. I can see it only when I exit this program. I want to override the menu in that dialog.

Can I do it , if so , how can I change it ? And why can't I see it on the activity I am in it ?

Comment: Im guessing the reason you are not seeing it on the activity you are in has something to do with not having the right context... could you post more details?

Comment: I've manage to find out what my problem was. I just transfer this lines to another activity.so thanks anyway.
but I still can't reach to the menu that this dialog box open.can I change this menu and his options ?